# Replacing Multiple Letters in a String with Each Other in Python

Tags: python, string, replace, reverse, bioinformatics

So I understand how to use str.replace() to replace single letters in a string, and I also know how to use the following replace_all function:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
for i, j in dic.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(i,j)
return text
```

But I am trying to replace letters with each other. For example replace each A with T and each T with A, each C with G and each G with C, but I end up getting a string composed of only two letters, either A and G or C and T, for example, and I know the output should be composed of four letters. Here is the code I have tried (I'd rather avoid built in functions):

```
d={'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'A': 'T', 'G': 'C'}
DNA_String = open('rosalind_rna.txt', 'r')
DNA_String = DNA_String.read()


reverse = str(DNA_String[::-1])


def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i,j)
    return text


complement = replace_all(reverse, d)
print complement
```

I also tried using:

```
complement = str.replace(reverse, 'A', 'T')
complement = str.replace(reverse, 'T', 'A')
complement = str.replace(reverse, 'G', 'C')
complement = str.replace(reverse, 'C', 'G')
```

But I end up getting a string that is four times as long as it should be.

I've also tried:

```
complement = str.replace(reverse, 'A', 'T').replace(reverse, 'T', 'A').replace(reverse, 'G', 'C')str.replace(reverse, 'C', 'G')
```

But I get an error message that an integer input is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can map each letter to another letter.

```
>>> M = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
>>> STR = 'CGAATT'
>>> S = "".join([M.get(c,c) for c in STR])
>>> S
'GCTTAA'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for this. Use [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) to create an according transition table.

```
>>> import string
>>> d ={'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
>>> s = "ACTG"
>>> _from, to = map(lambda t: ''.join(t), zip(*d.items()))
>>> t = string.maketrans(_from, to)
>>> s.translate(t)
'TGAC'
```

---

By the way, the error you get with this line

```
complement = str.replace(reverse, 'A', 'T').replace(reverse, 'T', 'A')...
```

is that you are explicitly passing the `self` keyword when it is passed implicitly. Doing `str.replace(reverse, 'A', 'T')` is equivalent to `reverse.replace('A', 'T')`. Accordingly, when you do `str.replace(...).replace(reverse, 'T', 'A')`, this is equivalent to `str.replace(str.replace(...), reverse, 'T', 'A')`, i.e. the result of the first replace is inserted as `self` in the other replace, and the other parameters are shifted and the `'A'` is interpreted as the [`count` parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), which has to be an `int`.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is happening because you're replacing all the `A`s with `T`s and *then* replacing all those `T`s (as well as those in the original string) with `A`s. Try replacing with lower-case letters and then converting the whole string with `upper()`:

```
dic = {'A': 't', 'T': 'a', 'C': 'g', 'G': 'c'}
text = 'GATTCCACCGT'
for i, j in dic.iteritems():
            text = text.replace(i,j)
text = text.upper()

gives:

'CTAAGGTGGCA'
```